# What did I still miss for remote connect to a SQL server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I installed SQL Server 2012 and Management Studio on a Windows Server 2008. I created database & table successfully using Management Studio. Then, I created a .udl file locally to test database connectivity and it works. The server is `<My server>/SQLEXPRESS` and authentication type is Windows authentication. I used the .udl file to see database I created and it approved the database server works at least locally well.

Now, I tried to test its connection remotely using the same way: .udl file. But it failed with error message:

> Login failed. The Login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

I am sure that I enabled TCP/IP connection with port 1433. I enabled SQL server & SQL server browser services are running (automatic) too.

The firewall is confirmed not the issue.

So, my question is that what makes the difference between local & remote connection. How come using the same way, local connection is OK but remote is not. Thanks.

Comment: Are both machines actually on the same domain?

Comment: Also, have you tried using SQL authentication just to confirm remote connectivity?

Comment: Yes, I tried using SQL authentication too. I got error: "Login failed for user 'sa'" or "Login failed for user "<My server name>/Administrator"

No domain set for both machines. They are at the same network.

Comment: They might be on the same network but it appears they are not on the same domain. Do you log on to a domain controller or just into the local machine? It's difficult (not impossible) to get windows authentication working on machines that aren't on a domain. You should at least be able to get SQL Authentication working.

Comment: Try creating a new SQL login, give it dbo access to your database then try remotely again.  sa may be locked to only allow local access.  Same network != same domain so that will not work.

Comment: SQL Server **Express** doesn't allow **remote connections** (connections from another machine) by default - you have to **explicitly enable** that feature.

Comment: Hi, Jane,
   I did the following and it works:

Comment: Oh good :)  I'm assuming that you had already followed the advice of @marc_s and enable remote connections to your SQL Express?

Comment: Hi, Jane,
   I did the following and it works:

1. Change the Authenticate type to "Mixed mode":

  > Right click on the SQL server name, choose "Property", in General, set Server Authentication mode as "SQl Server & Windows Authentication Mode"

  > In "Status", I Enabled the login.

  > In Security / Logins / sa: In "General", I set password and in "Status", I select Login as Enabled.

  > Right-clicked the SQL server again and choose "Restart".

  > Used .udl file to test connectivity again. It works.

Thanks Jane a lot.

Comment: Also thanks Nick.McDermaid & marc_s.

Comment: An embarrassed question: I don't know how to mark this question as resolved and how to mark the answers working. I found the way http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers  doesn't work. That's, I can't follow the instruction: 
To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in

Comment: I used user name: sa and password which I set using Management Studio to test connectivity.

Comment: Simply put an answer in to the text box below, then accept it.  Note there may be a 15 minute delay before it will allow you to do so, but I'm not sure if it applies to your own self-answered questions.

Comment: The problem is that I can't find the 'Check' in beside the text box. It seems I was get rid of the right to accept an answer. It's really strange. I did it before without any problem. It's strange to have to accept an anwer within 15 minute. I must keep an eye on it?

Comment: @StanHuangatTaiwan You will need to just answer the question as you would any other.  Once you have submitted the answer, you should be able to accept it with the checkbox at that time.